# Selenium - How to get the values options of a Select field - PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have this follow select field:

```
<select size="4" name="ctl00$_contentPlaceHolderOiLegal$lstRequisicoes" id="ctl00__contentPlaceHolderOiLegal_lstRequisicoes" tabindex="67">
   <option value="103122 - Registration data [1]">103122 - Registration data [1]</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="103123 - Sittel - Extrato com cadastro de interlocutor [2]">103123 - Sittel - Extract with contact record [2]</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the values of the field and transform it in a Array?

I tried the but it isn´t working:

```
   name = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00__contentPlaceHolderOiLegal_lstRequisicoes").get_attribute("value")

    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use following code :**

```
    listOfOptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@id='ctl00__contentPlaceHolderOiLegal_lstRequisicoes']//option')

option_value_array[]

    for option in listOfOptions:

        option_value = option.text
        option_value_array.append(option_value)
        print (option_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of selected dropdwon try this.You need to import `select` Let me know is that you are looking after.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00__contentPlaceHolderOiLegal_lstRequisicoes"))
seltext = select.first_selected_option
print(seltext.text)
```

Output:

```
103123 - Sittel - Extract with contact record [2]
```

Or

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select    select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00__contentPlaceHolderOiLegal_lstRequisicoes"))
    seltext = select.first_selected_option
    print(seltext.get_attribute('value'))
```

OutPut:

```
103123 - Sittel - Extrato com cadastro de interlocutor [2]
```